# How to view the data from the database in json format

Tags: json, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am trying to pass the data from the database to the controller through a service (WCF Data Service), which is an independent application. While running the service for testing, the data is shown in XML format. I need to view the data in JSON format. Any solutions??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am doing this in C#.Net VS2012

Answer (score 0):

For JSON support:

Download the JSONPSupportBehavior.cs from the [Microsoft Code Gallery](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DataServicesJSONP)

Locate the JSONPSupportBehavior.cs file in the downloaded project and include it in your web project.

Add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.

Mark your service with the JSONPSupportBehavior attribute.

```
[JSONPSupportBehavior]
public class WcfDataService : DataService<SampleDbEntities>
```

Please refer this link
[A Beginner's Tutorial for Creating WCF Data Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/572417/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusforplusCreatingpl)

Hope this helps

Comment: How can i do this in WCF Data Service?

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data services supports JSON out of the box.

In order to receive a response in JSON format, you can include application/json in the accept header of the request. Or you can use $format=json in your request url.